# algorithm to convert from array of decimal to array of binary in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16

i am doing a project to convert an array of decmial numbers to an array of binary
in assembly emu8086 , i have an idea of how to do it , but i need more help understanding arrays in assembly , the idea is to take each number and convert it to binary then add the representations to get the result

```
arrayD 1 2 3 4 
1->1000-> binary1
2->200 -> binary2
3->30 -> binary3
4-> binary4

add binary1,binary2,binary3,binary4
```

is it doable in assembly language ?

Comment: Just to check if I understand, do you want to take numbers, change them to binary (base 2) and store them in an array? If that's the case, you will have to convert them to string, so you will have an array of strings. Am I following you?

Comment: for example i have the number 334 to convert to binary ... but it is represented in an array as 3,3,4  ... i have to convert each number then add each representation then put the result in an array

Comment: I'm confused. Let's see: we have an array with 3 items: 3, 3 and 4. The result must be another array with 9 items : 1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1 and 0. Is that so?

Comment: no ... convert 300 to binary1 ... convert 30 to binary2 ... convert 4 to binary 3 ... then add binary1+binary2+binary3 .... put the result in an array

Comment: Anything is doable in assembly. Now, the rule is: the last number in array is multiplied by 10^0, the previous number 10^1, and so on until we reach the first number in array multiplied by 10^(n-1). Is this it?

Comment: yaa that's it  , is it difficult to do  in assembly ?

Comment: Everything is difficult to do in assembly . . . but it's doable.

Comment: i already started with code ... if i have problems i'll post it .. thank you

Comment: Do you only need to store the numbers into another array, not displaying them, right? Another question, the first array has numbers of one digit only or more?

Comment: actually i have to display the resulted array too .... and the first array only has one digit numbers

Comment: Elias, I'm not sure if my answer worked for you. If you still need help, just post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your problem, just copy-paste in EMU8086 and run, fully commented to help you understand, it takes the one-digit numbers stored in an array, multiply each one by a power of then (0..n, from right to left), and stores those numbers in a second array, at the end everything is displayed (the original array, the new array, and the total sum):

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

arr1   dw 1,5,2,4,3         ;ARRAY OF ONE DIGIT NUMBERS.
arr2   dw 5 dup(?)          ;ARRAY FOR CONVERTED NUMBERS. 
len    dw 5                 ;LENGTH OF ARRAYS.
tot    dw ?                 ;SUM OF ALL CONVERTED NUMBERS.
msj1   db 'The first array is:',13,10,'$'
msj2   db 'The resulting array is:',13,10,'$'
msj3   db 'The total sum is:',13,10,'$'
buffer db 6 dup(?)          ;USED TO CONVERT NUMBERS TO STRING.
linbrk db 13,10,'$'         ;LINE BREAK.

.code
start:

;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax, @data
  mov  ds, ax

;TASKS.                    
  call process_arrays
  call sum_array
  call clear_screen
  call display_arr1
  call display_arr2
  call total_sum

;WAIT FOR ANY KEY.    
  mov  ah, 7
  int  21h

;FINISH PROGRAM.
  mov  ax, 4c00h
  int  21h

;-----------------------------------------
;MULTIPLY EACH NUMBER IN ARRAY1 BY 10^?, AND
;STORE THE RESULT IN ARRAY2. THE LAST NUMBER
;IS MULTIPLIED BY 10^0, THE PREVIOUS NUMBER
;IS MULTIPLIED BY 10^1, AND SO ON, EXAMPLE:
;   ARR1 = [ 1,5,2,4,3 ].
;PROCESS = 3 * 10^0
;          4 * 10^1
;          2 * 10^2
;          5 * 10^3
;          1 * 10^4
;   ARR2 = [ 10000,5000,200,40,3 ]. 

process_arrays proc

;INITIALIZATIONS.
  mov  cx, len              ;LENGTH OF ARRAYS.
  shl  cx, 1                ;CX*2, NECESSARY BECAUSE EVERY NUMBER IS 2 BYTES LONG.
  mov  si, offset arr1      ;SI POINTS TO FIRST NUMBER.
  add  si, cx               ;NOW SI POINTS BEYOND THE LAST NUMBER.
  sub  si, 2                ;NOW SI POINTS TO THE LAST NUMBER.
  mov  di, offset arr2      ;DI POINTS TO FIRST POSITION.
  add  di, cx               ;NOW DI POINTS BEYOND THE LAST POSITION.
  sub  di, 2                ;NOW DI POINTS TO THE LAST POSITION.
  mov  cx, len              ;REVERSE COUNTER (TO KNOW WHEN TO FINISH).
  mov  bp, 0                ;FIRST POWER OF 10: 10^0.

converting:

;CALCULATE 10^?.
  cmp  bp, 0
  je   first_time           ;SPECIAL CASE: 10^0.
  mov  ax, 10
  mul  bp                   ;AX * BP = 10*BP (10*1, 10*10, 10*100, 10*1000).
  mov  bp, ax               ;STORE RESULT OF MUL (AX) IN BP.
  jmp  not_first_time       ;THIS JUMP IS TO SKIP MOV BP, 1.
first_time: 
  mov  bp, 1                ;10^0 = 1.
not_first_time:  

;MULTIPLY CURRENT NUMBER BY 10^?.
  mov  ax, [ si ]           ;AX = CURRENT NUMBER.
  mul  bp                   ;AX * BP (CURRENT_NUMBER * 10^?).

;STORE RESULT IN THE OTHER ARRAY.
  mov  [ di ], ax

;MOVE TO NEXT POSITION IN ARRAYS. WE GO BACKWARDS BECAUSE WE MOVE
;FROM THE LEAST SIGNIFICANT DIGIT TO THE MOST (FROM RIGHT TO LEFT).
  sub  si, 2                ;MINUS 2 BECAUSE EACH NUMBER
  sub  di, 2                ;IS TWO BYTES LONG (DW).

  loop converting           ;CX--. IF (CX > 0) JUMP.

  ret
process_arrays endp    

;-----------------------------------------
;SUM ALL NUMBERS IN ARRAY2, EXAMPLE:
;   ARR2 = [ 10000,5000,200,40,3 ].
;PROCESS = 10000 + 5000 + 200 + 40 + 3 = 15.243.

sum_array proc
  mov  si, offset arr2
  mov  cx, len              ;REVERSE COUNTER.
  mov  ax, 0                ;TOTAL.
sums:  
  add  ax, [ si ]           ;SUM CURRENT NUMBER.
  add  si, 2                ;NEXT NUMBER IN ARRAY (2 BECAUSE NUMBER IS DW).
  loop sums                 ;CX--. IF (CX > 0) JUMP.
  mov  tot, ax

  ret
sum_array endp

;-----------------------------------------

display_arr1 proc

;DISPLAY MESSAGE.    
  mov  dx, offset msj1    
  call printf

;DISPLAY NUMBERS.
  mov  si, offset arr1  
  mov  cx, len
displ_a1:
  mov  ax, [ si ]           ;GET CURRENT NUMBER.
  push cx                   ;PRESERVE COUNTER (IT WILL BE MODIFIED).
  push si                   ;PRESERVE POINTER (IT WILL BE MODIFIED).
;CONVERT CURRENT NUMBER TO STRING.              
  mov  si, offset buffer    ;PARAMETER FOR NUMBER2STRING.
  call number2string        ;CONVERT AX IN STRING POINTED BY SI.        
;DISPLAY STRING.  
  mov  dx, offset buffer    ;STRING TO DISPLAY.   
  call printf
  mov  dx, offset linbrk    ;LINE BREAK.
  call printf

  pop  si                   ;RESTORE POINTER.
  pop  cx                   ;RESTORE COUNTER.
  add  si, 2                ;NEXT NUMBER IN ARRAY (2 BECAUSE NUMBER IS DW).
  loop displ_a1             ;CX--. IF (CX > 0) JUMP.

  ret
display_arr1 endp

;-----------------------------------------

display_arr2 proc

;DISPLAY MESSAGE.    
  mov  dx, offset msj2    
  call printf

;DISPLAY NUMBERS.
  mov  si, offset arr2  
  mov  cx, len
displ_a2:
  mov  ax, [ si ]           ;GET CURRENT NUMBER.
  push cx                   ;PRESERVE COUNTER (IT WILL BE MODIFIED).
  push si                   ;PRESERVE POINTER (IT WILL BE MODIFIED).
;CONVERT CURRENT NUMBER TO STRING.              
  mov  si, offset buffer    ;PARAMETER FOR NUMBER2STRING.
  call number2string        ;CONVERT AX IN STRING POINTED BY SI.        
;DISPLAY STRING.  
  mov  dx, offset buffer    ;STRING TO DISPLAY.   
  call printf
  mov  dx, offset linbrk    ;LINE BREAK.
  call printf

  pop  si                   ;RESTORE POINTER.
  pop  cx                   ;RESTORE COUNTER.
  add  si, 2                ;NEXT NUMBER IN ARRAY (2 BECAUSE NUMBER IS DW).
  loop displ_a2             ;CX--. IF (CX > 0) JUMP.

  ret
display_arr2 endp

;-----------------------------------------

total_sum proc

;CONVERT SUM TO STRING.              
  mov  ax, tot              ;PARAMETER FOR NUMBER2STRING (NUMBER TO CONVERT).
  mov  si, offset buffer    ;PARAMETER FOR NUMBER2STRING (DESTINATION STRING).
  call number2string        ;CONVERT AX IN STRING POINTED BY SI.        

;DISPLAY MESSAGE.    
  mov  dx, offset msj3
  call printf

;DISPLAY STRING.  
  mov  dx, offset buffer    ;STRING TO DISPLAY.   
  call printf

  ret
total_sum endp    

;-----------------------------------------
;PARAMETER : DX POINTING TO '$' FINISHED STRING.

printf proc
  mov  ah, 9
  int  21h
  ret
printf endp    

;-----------------------------------------

clear_screen proc
  mov  ah, 0
  mov  al, 3
  int  10H
  ret
clear_screen endp

;------------------------------------------
;CONVERT A NUMBER IN STRING.
;ALGORITHM : EXTRACT DIGITS ONE BY ONE, STORE
;THEM IN STACK, THEN EXTRACT THEM IN REVERSE
;ORDER TO CONSTRUCT STRING (STR).
;PARAMETERS : AX = NUMBER TO CONVERT.
;             SI = POINTING WHERE TO STORE STRING.
number2string proc
;FILL BUFFER WITH '$' (NECESSARY TO DISPLAY).    
  push si                   ;PRESERVE POINTER (IT WILL BE MODIFIED).
  call dollars              ;FILL BUFFER WITH '$' (NECESSARY TO DISPLAY). 
  pop  si                   ;RESTORE POINTER.

  mov  bx, 10               ;DIGITS ARE EXTRACTED DIVIDING BY 10.
  mov  cx, 0                ;COUNTER FOR EXTRACTED DIGITS.
cycle1:       
  mov  dx, 0                ;NECESSARY TO DIVIDE BY BX.
  div  bx                   ;DX:AX / 10 = AX:QUOTIENT DX:REMAINDER.
  push dx                   ;PRESERVE DIGIT EXTRACTED FOR LATER.
  inc  cx                   ;INCREASE COUNTER FOR EVERY DIGIT EXTRACTED.
  cmp  ax, 0                ;IF NUMBER IS
  jne  cycle1               ;NOT ZERO, LOOP. 
;NOW RETRIEVE PUSHED DIGITS.
cycle2:  
  pop  dx        
  add  dl, 48               ;CONVERT DIGIT TO CHARACTER.
  mov  [ si ], dl
  inc  si
  loop cycle2  

  ret
number2string endp  

;------------------------------------------
;FILLS VARIABLE WITH '$'.
;USED BEFORE CONVERT NUMBERS TO STRING, BECAUSE
;THE STRING WILL BE DISPLAYED.
;PARAMETER : SI = POINTING TO STRING TO FILL.

dollars proc
  mov  cx, 6
six_dollars:      
  mov  bl, '$'
  mov  [ si ], bl
  inc  si
  loop six_dollars

  ret
dollars endp  

end start
```

I hard coded the numbers in array1 (1,5,2,4,3), you can change this numbers (but be careful, the total sum **must not** exceed 65535). This is what is does (example):

```
ARRAY1 = [ 1,5,2,4,3 ].
PROCESS = 3 * 10^0
          4 * 10^1
          2 * 10^2
          5 * 10^3
          1 * 10^4
ARRAY2 = [ 10000,5000,200,40,3 ]. 
SUM    = 15243
```

I'm not sure if another process is required: to convert each number of array2 into binary format and display again, just let me know.

Answer (score -1):

```
model small 
.stack 100h .data result db ? 
array1 db 10,20,30,40 
.code  start: 
movax,@data 
movds,ax 

movsi,offset array1 movcx,lengthof array1 
mov al,0 L1: add al,[si] incsi 
Loop L1 
movresult,al 

movdx,offset result  
mov ah,9 
int 21h 

mov ah,4ch int 21h 
end start
```

Comment: `int 21h` / `ah=9` takes a pointer to a `$`-teminated string http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09.  You're passing it a pointer to a 1-byte integer.   DOS doesn't have int->string printing system calls, so the first character printed is just the one byte you calculated.  ASCII code `90` is capital-`Z`, so that's the first byte of output, then carriage-return (`10`), then nonsense until it finds a `$` somewhere or crashes.